# Difficulty getting params for multiple records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with three separate models, we'll call them: Admins, Products and Reviews.  Products have many Reviews and Reviews belong to Products while Admins are independent. If a Product or Review is not helpful or considered spam any visitor to the site has the option of flagging it for review.  In the Admin control panel Admins can see the products and the reviews in question and edit or delete them.  I can show both reviews and products that have been flagged by users but I can't show them together; for example, say a user flags a review I'll be able to see it but I won't know which product it's under because generally whenever I try to access the Product record it dosen't know what the params are.  Since `@reviews = Review.where("flag > ?", 0).order("flag DESC")` will return ALL flagged reviews there will be most often more then one so simply saying `@product = Product.find(id: @reviews.product_id)` won't work, however I believe I need something like this which can be applied to each individual review as it loops through all flagged reviews before displaying them with `@reviews.each do |review|`

admin_controller

```
def show
   @Admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
   @products = Product.where("flag > ?", 0).order("flag DESC")
   @reviews = Review.where("flag > ?", 0).order("flag DESC")
   @singleProduct = Product.find(id: Review.product_id)  # this is the line that I'm not quite sure of, I want to be able to grab each review.product_id as they loop through on the show.html.erb page to show what product goes with the review.  I realize that calling @reviews.product_id would return multiple ids since there are, theoretically, more then one reviews with flags.
end
```

Show.html.erb

```
      <% if @review.blank? %>
         Nothing to review!
      <% else %>
      <div class="list-group">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
            <li class="list-group-item">  <%= review.comment %> Review Flagged:
              <%= pluralize(review.flag, 'time', plural: 'times') %>.   <%=  @singleProduct.name   #Again, I'm not sure how to implement this but I want it to grab the product_id of each @review as |review| loops to show however many flagged reviews there are.%>
 <%= link_to 'View',  product_review_path(Product, review) %>

               <%= link_to 'Delete',  product_review_path(Product, review), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this review?"} %> </li>
            <% end %>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're referring to what is called [eager loading](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/). When you initially fetch the `Review` records you can also fetch their `Product` data so that when you iterate over the reviews and call their associated product, it won't need to make another call to the database. However I'm a bit confused by your choice in model associations so I could be wrong with what you're trying to do.

```
# controller
def show
  @Admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
  @products = Product.where("flag > ?", 0).order("flag DESC")
  @reviews = Review.includes(:products).where("flag > ?", 0).order("flag DESC")
end


# show.html.erb
<% if @review.blank? %>
  Nothing to review!
<% else %>
  <div class="list-group">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
      <li class="list-group-item">  <%= review.comment %> Review Flagged:
          <%= pluralize(review.flag, 'time', plural: 'times') %>. <%=  @review.product.name %>
          <%= link_to 'View',  product_review_path(Product, review) %>
          <%= link_to 'Delete',  product_review_path(Product, review), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this review?"} %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work.  I will give that article a more thorough reading today.